# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - JSON/JQUERY/Data.error

Tags: php, ajax

**AJAX**

```
$("body").on("click", "#formSubmit", function() {

  var args = {
    action: 'addToDB',
    id: $(".id:checked").getEach('value'),
  };

  $.post("/post/URL", args, function(data) {

    if (data.errors.length > 0) {
      alert(getErrorList(data.errors));
    } else {
      // What to do after no errors
    }
  });
});
```

The above is supposed to send arguments to the db

```
if ($data['action'] == 'addToDB') {   
    $results = [     
       "errors" => [],   
    ];

    if (empty($data['id'])){ 
        // Supposed to error out when id is not supplied
        $results['errors'][] = "Please select a question to add.";   
    }   
    else {   
        // DB Insert data if no errors
    } 
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"` in console. When I console log `data` I can see the error text but `undefined` when i try to console log `data.errors`.

Comment: can you provide us with your Data object, it sounds that you have an array of data

Comment: I added the rest of the ajax with the args

Comment: There is no `data.error`.  You defined `data.errors`.

Comment: Sorry I meant data.errors is undefined I made the change to my post

Comment: It looks like you forgot to decode your Json Object :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $.post send back an encoded Data on JSON, you have to decode the object before you use it in your function.

You code should be like this :

```
$.post("/post/URL", args, function(data){
  // you have to decode your JSON object before you use it
  var data = $.parseJSON(result);

  if (data.errors.length > 0){
      alert(getErrorList(data.errors)); 
  } 
  else {
      // What to do after no errors
  }
});
```

**Here is a Working example**

```
<html>
<head><title></title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").click("#formSubmit", function () {

                var args = {
                    action: 'addToDB',
                    id: 1
                };

                $.post("test2.php", args, function(result){
                    var data = $.parseJSON(result);

                    if (data.errors.length > 0){
                        alert("Yes, It is working :), you have got " + data.errors.length + " error(s)");
                        //alert(getErrorList(data.errors));
                    }
                    else {
                            // What to do after no errors
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I meant data.errors is undefined and tried it without the "s" and still the same issue of undefined in the console log.

Comment: Can you share your Data object structure ? like i have said before it sounds that you have a wrong structure in your data object

Comment: Not sure how I grab that kinda new to OOP but  `{"errors":["Please select a question to add."]}`
thats what I get when I console log `data` and when I try `data.errors` I get `undefined`

Comment: Just use the $.parseJSON() function like i have done in the example above and you will be fine